# Codeigniter: Cookies and sessions

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am setting cookies in CodeIgniter as `$this->input->set_cookie('email',$e)`; then I am trying to access the cookie using `$this->input->cookie('email')`.

But it is not giving any answer. I tried using `var_dump($this->input->cookie('email'));` and it gives `bool(false)` as answer.

Can anybody tell me why the cookie is not being set? I have loaded the cookie helper too.

Here is the code

```
function login_success()
    {
        $e=$_POST['login_email'];
        $p=$_POST['login_password'];
        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta"); 

        $session_data=array("email"=>$e,"password"=>$p,"is_logged_in"=>true);

        $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
        $this->input->set_cookie('email', $e);
        $this->input->set_cookie('password', $p);
        $this->input->set_cookie('cookie_set', true);
        $data=array('last_login'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),'last_login_ip'=>$this->input->ip_address());
        var_dump($this->input->cookie('email')) ;
    }
```

Comment: When are you fetching them? Cookies are available only at the next request

Comment: I am sorry i don't know what next request means.In the same function i first create a session and then set the cookies.The session is being set successfully but cookies are not set

Comment: Next request represents after page reload or navigation. In simple, you cannot set the cookie in the first line and check whether it exists in the next lines.

Comment: put the 'var_dump($this->input->cookie('email'));' as the first line of the function and you will see what is happening as regards the 'email' cookie. it will be 'false' the first time then it will be set on the second time through.

Comment: In the next function call i checked whether the cookie is set or not.Still showing bool false :(

Comment: Have you tried setting a 'test' cookie in the controller to ensure that user cookies are being returned correctly? Your logic here looks reasonable as given, especially as the email cookie is displayed as soon as you enter this function.

Comment: You need to do a new http request in order to have a cookie set, not just call the same function (which one, anyway?) twice

Comment: Its bad idea to store password in cookie, try $this->input->set_cookie('cookie_set', '1');

Comment: after the above function executes(ajax call this controller function) , ajax loads another page as response:---> header(//some address);the address is that of another controller func which checks whether the cookie is set or not .Still showing not set

Comment: @saquieb thanks i will keep that in mind.but still i don't have the answer to my question